# Why in a TCP server/client model, the server copies every packet the client sends and sends it as well?

Tags: c++, networking, tcp, wireshark, handshake

So I wanted to learn more on how the TCP protocol works and started messing with windows sockets (WinSocks2), I managed to write a basic server and client from the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/about-clients-and-servers).

I expected to see a 3-way handshake in Wireshark, and I did but not in the way I imagined, it was actually duplicated (The server sends the same packets as the client back to the client).

**So my question is, is this normal, or am I doing something wrong?**

Here is my source code of the server:

```
// This should be placed before #include <Windows.h> if the windows include is used
#ifndef WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#endif
 
#include <cstdio>
 
#include <Windows.h>
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
 
/// TEST CODE /// REMOVE AFTER TESTING WAS DONE ///
int main()
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult;
 
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0)
    {
        printf("WSAStartup failed: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }
 
    struct addrinfo* result = NULL, * ptr = NULL, hints;
 
    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
 
    // Resolve the local address and port to be used by the server
    iResult = getaddrinfo("0.0.0.0", "1337", &hints, &result);
    if (iResult != 0)
    {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
 
    SOCKET ListenSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    
    if (ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Error at socket(): %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        WSACleanup();
    }
 
    iResult = bind(ListenSocket, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("bind failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
 
    freeaddrinfo(result);
        
    if (listen(ListenSocket, SOMAXCONN) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("Listen failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
 
    // Handling pending connections
 
    puts("Waiting for a connection..");
    SOCKET ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);
    if (ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("accept failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
 
    #define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512
 
    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    int iSendResult;
    int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;
    int size =0 ;
 
    // Receive until the peer shuts down the connection
    do
    {
        iResult = recv(ClientSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
        if (iResult > 0)
        {
            printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);
            size += iResult;
 
            // I thought this was the problem but after I removed it from the code it still was the same.
            //
            // Echo the buffer back to the sender
            //iSendResult = send(ClientSocket, recvbuf, iResult, 0);
            /*if (iSendResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
                printf("send failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
                closesocket(ClientSocket);
                WSACleanup();
                return 1;
            }*/
            //printf("Bytes sent: %d\n", iSendResult);
        }
        else if (iResult == 0)
            printf("Connection closing...\n");
        else
        {
            printf("recv failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(ClientSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }
 
    }
    while (iResult > 0);
 
    recvbuf[size] = 0;
    printf("Data received: %s\n", recvbuf);
 
    // Stops responding to requests, still can accept tho
    iResult = shutdown(ClientSocket, SD_SEND);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("shutdown failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ClientSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
 
    // Close socket, no receiving/sending
    closesocket(ClientSocket);
    WSACleanup();
}
```

And here is the client:

```
// This should be placed before #include <Windows.h> if the windows include is used
#ifndef WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#endif
 
#include <cstdio>
 
#include <Windows.h>
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
 
/// TEST CODE /// REMOVE AFTER TESTING WAS DONE ///
int main()
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult;
 
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0)
    {
        printf("WSAStartup failed: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }
 
    struct addrinfo* result = NULL, * ptr = NULL, hints;
 
    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
 
    // Resolve the local address and port to be used by the server
    iResult = getaddrinfo("109.xxx.xxx.xxx", "1337", &hints, &result);
    if (iResult != 0)
    {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
 
    SOCKET ConnectSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
 
    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Error at socket(): %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        WSACleanup();
    }
 
    iResult = connect(ConnectSocket, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)    
    {
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    }
 
    // Should really try the next address returned by getaddrinfo
    // if the connect call failed
    // But for this simple example we just free the resources
    // returned by getaddrinfo and print an error message
 
    freeaddrinfo(result);
 
    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Unable to connect to server!\n");
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
 
 
 
    #define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512
 
    int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;
 
    const char* sendbuf = "this is a test";
    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
 
    // Send an initial buffer
    iResult = send(ConnectSocket, sendbuf, (int)strlen(sendbuf), 0);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("send failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
 
    printf("Bytes Sent: %ld\n", iResult);
 
    // shutdown the connection for sending since no more data will be sent
    // the client can still use the ConnectSocket for receiving data
    iResult = shutdown(ConnectSocket, SD_SEND);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("shutdown failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
 
    // Receive data until the server closes the connection
    do
    {
        iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
        if (iResult > 0)
            printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);
        else if (iResult == 0)
            printf("Connection closed\n");
        else
            printf("recv failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    }
    while (iResult > 0);
 
    closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    WSACleanup();
}
```

Here is the packets captured from Wireshark, where the IP address starting with `109.xxx.xxx.xxx` is the server:

[image]

Comment: Please include your code as part of the question.

Comment: I posted it on pastebin, otherwise it will make the question a lot more longer, I will do though

Comment: Reading the packet capture on imgur is annoying. You'll get better response if you copy a couple meaningful packets and highlight where you think what you see is incorrect. E.g.: here in this packet, we see [blah], I expected [foo].

Comment: In Windows btw it's easier to use WSAConnect.

Answer (score 0):

No, the duplicate packets are not normal. But that is not related to your code. It is more likely an issue with your network setup, or just a side effect of how you are capturing the packets.

---

Unrelated to the duplicate packets, there are other problems with the code shown.

In your server:

- your `if (ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)` block is missing a `return`, so if `socket()` fails then you still call `bind()` with an invalid `SOCKET` and are dereferencing an invalid `result` pointer.
- Once you reach your `recv()` loop, you are never closing the `ListenSocket` before calling `WSACleanup()`.
- your `printf()` of `recvbuf` needs to be inside the loop when `iResult > 0`. And if you are going to null-terminate `recvbuf` then you need to use `recvbuflen-1` when calling `recv()`, or else you will lose the last byte received. Otherwise, pass `iResult` as a parameter to `printf()` so you don't need to null-terminate `recvbuf` at all.

In your client:

- do not use the `AI_PASSIVE` flag when calling `getaddrinfo()`.  That flag is meant for listening servers, not outbound clients.
- your `if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)` block is missing a `return`, so if `socket()` fails then you still call `connect()` with an invalid `SOCKET` and are dereferencing an invalid `result` pointer.

Try this code instead:

server:

```
// This should be placed before #include <Windows.h> if the windows include is used
#ifndef WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#endif
 
#include <cstdio>
 
#include <Windows.h>
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
 
/// TEST CODE /// REMOVE AFTER TESTING WAS DONE ///
int main()
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult;
 
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0)
    {
        printf("WSAStartup failed: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }
 
    struct addrinfo* result = NULL, hints;
 
    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
 
    // Resolve the local address and port to be used by the server
    iResult = getaddrinfo(NULL, "1337", &hints, &result);
    if (iResult != 0)
    {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
 
    SOCKET ListenSocket = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);      
    if (ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Error at socket(): %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
 
    iResult = bind(ListenSocket, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("bind failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
 
    freeaddrinfo(result);
        
    if (listen(ListenSocket, SOMAXCONN) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("Listen failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
 
    // Handling pending connections
 
    puts("Waiting for a connection..");

    SOCKET ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);
    if (ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("accept failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
 
    #define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512
 
    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    int iSendResult;
 
    // Receive until the peer shuts down the connection
    do
    {
        iResult = recv(ClientSocket, recvbuf, sizeof(recvbuf), 0);
        if (iResult > 0)
        {
            printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);
            printf("Data received: %.*s\n", iResult, recvbuf);
 
            // Echo the buffer back to the sender
            /*iSendResult = send(ClientSocket, recvbuf, iResult, 0);
            if (iSendResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
                printf("send failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
                break;
            }
            printf("Bytes sent: %d\n", iSendResult);*/
        }
        else if (iResult == 0)
        {
            printf("Connection closing...\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("recv failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        }    
    }
    while (iResult > 0);

    // Close socket, no receiving/sending
    shutdown(ClientSocket, SD_BOTH);
    closesocket(ClientSocket);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

client:

```
// This should be placed before #include <Windows.h> if the windows include is used
#ifndef WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#endif
 
#include <cstdio>
 
#include <Windows.h>
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
 
/// TEST CODE /// REMOVE AFTER TESTING WAS DONE ///
int main()
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult;
 
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0)
    {
        printf("WSAStartup failed: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }
 
    struct addrinfo* result = NULL, hints;
 
    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
 
    // Resolve the local address and port to be used by the server
    iResult = getaddrinfo("109.xxx.xxx.xxx", "1337", &hints, &result);
    if (iResult != 0)
    {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
 
    SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    for(struct addrinfo* ptr = result; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->ai_next)
    {
        ConnectSocket = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype, ptr->ai_protocol);
        if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            printf("Error at socket(): %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            freeaddrinfo(result);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }
 
        iResult = connect(ConnectSocket, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen);
        freeaddrinfo(result);

        if (iResult != SOCKET_ERROR)
            break;

        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    }
 
    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Unable to connect to server!\n");
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
 
    #define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512
 
    const char* sendbuf = "this is a test";
    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
 
    // Send an initial buffer
    iResult = send(ConnectSocket, sendbuf, (int)strlen(sendbuf), 0);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("send failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
 
    printf("Bytes Sent: %ld\n", iResult);
 
    // shutdown the connection for sending since no more data will be sent
    // the client can still use the ConnectSocket for receiving data
    iResult = shutdown(ConnectSocket, SD_SEND);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("shutdown failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
 
    // Receive data until the server closes the connection
    do
    {
        iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, sizeof(recvbuf), 0);
        if (iResult > 0)
            printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);
        else if (iResult == 0)
            printf("Connection closed\n");
        else
            printf("recv failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    }
    while (iResult > 0);
 
    shutdown(ConnectSocket, SD_RECEIVE);
    closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```